What is the number of events within an interval with Gamma-distributed waiting times?
Suppose I have a renewal process with continuous time and the time intervals between events follow the $X_i \sim Gamma(\alpha,\beta)$ distribution (i.i.d.).
The question I have is what is the distribution of the number of events in an interval of length $T$?
I can show that the waiting time  for $k$-th event has distribution $S_k \sim Gamma(k\alpha,\beta)$, denote its CDF as $F_k(t)$.
The number of events I am looking for is $N(T) = \max \{ k | S_k < T \}$
I can show that:
$P(N(T)=k) = F_k(T) \cdot (1 - F_{k+1}(T))$.
I can also show that for $\alpha = 1$, $N(T) \sim Poisson(T\beta)$.
But what is the distribution of $N(T)$ for a general $\alpha$? The Gamma CDF is expressed using the incomplete gamma functions and it doesn't seem possible to manipulate it in the above formula using elementary methods into a reasonable form.
EDIT: I found a theorem which says that
$$ \mathcal{L}_T \left(PGF_{N(T)}(z)\right)(r) = \frac{1-\phi(r)}{r(1-z\phi(r))}, $$
where $\mathcal{L}$ is the Laplace transform and $\phi(r) = \mathcal{L}_t\left( f_{X_i}(t)\right)(r) = \frac{\beta^\alpha}{(\beta+r)^{\alpha}}$ in this case.
After playing a bit with this in CAS, I conjecture that:
$$P(N(T)=k) = \frac{Γ(α(k+1), βT)}{Γ(α(k+1))} - \frac{Γ(αk,  βT)}{Γ(αk)}$$
Which doesn't remind me of a usual distribution? I can't do a formal proof as I am unable to compute the Laplace transform or the inverse Laplace transform analytically.

It is not a typical distribution as the derivation below for integer $\alpha$ demonstrates. So, for non-integer $\alpha$ your comparisons with CDF functions seems to be the best you can do.

For integer values of $\alpha$ the gamma distribution is a sum of exponential distributions. Then you can model the events $X_i$ by events $Y_i$ where the difference between the events $Y_i$ is exponentially distributed. The event $Y_{\alpha i}$ corresponds to the event $X_i$.
Let the number of events $Y$ within the interval be $N_Y$ (and we know it is Poisson distributed).
Then the number of events $X$ within the interval, $N_X$, can be related to $N_Y$
$$N_X = \lfloor N_Y/\alpha \rfloor$$
and it is a sort of Poisson distribution that is binned into bins of size $\alpha$.
